# Should the .lock file get deleted after the workspace is closed normally in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Based on my learning, I am under the impression that the '.lock' file that gets created in the 'metadata' folder of an eclipse workspace should get deleted once the workspace is closed normally.

But it did not when I checked...

Please let me know if my understanding is correct or not?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Prasad

Answer (score 2):

It most probably should but sometimes it doesn't. Refer [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=78582) documented bug for more details. Delete the `.lock` file manually.

Comment: @Prasad, if you found it helpful, I'd appreicate it if you accept my answer and upvote it.

Comment: I think the most accurate answer from the link provided was: Since 3.0, the simple existence of the .lock file does not mean
anything (other than the workspace has been used before), because we don't
delete it anymore.  The default locking
mechanism  uses java.nio.channels file locking support. When Eclipse exits (or
crashes), the lock on the .lock file is released, but the file is not deleted.